# Why is it not possible to change System.in more than once in Java?

Tags: java, junit, java-io

I'm using JUnit to test my program that has console input, and I use ByteArrays to simulate console input and output. But for some reason, when I use System.setIn(IS) at the end of the first test, it doesn't actually change System.in. Also in second test, when I try to put new ByteArray as System.in, it doesn't happend and my second test fails to pass... So why is that the case? 

 Edit: My Utility class uses Scanner to read from System.in. :

```
public static String readText() {
    while (true) {
        String unos = sc.nextLine();
        if (!unos.isEmpty()) {
            return unos;
        }
        System.out.println("Niste ništa uneli, pokušajte ponovo: ");
    }
}

public static String read() {
    String unos = sc.nextLine();
    return unos;
}
```

And these are my tests:

```
private final InputStream IS = System.in;
private final PrintStream PS = System.out;

@Test
public void testRead() {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("\nNeki tekst\nasdasdasd".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);

    assertEquals("", Utility.read());
    assertEquals("Neki tekst", Utility.read());

    System.setIn(IS);
}

@Test
public void testReadText() {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("\nNeki tekst2\n".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
    assertEquals("Neki tekst2", Utility.readText());
    assertEquals("Niste ništa uneli, pokušajte ponovo: " + System.getProperty("line.separator"), out.toString());

    System.setIn(IS);
    System.setOut(PS);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `setIn` isn't working the second time? What is your Utility class?

Comment: Your currently posted code makes no sense to me. You can `read()` after setting `System.in`, but `sc` is already initialized there, so it gets initialized before you change `System.in`, so how do you expect it to read from your `ByteArrayInputStream` instead?

Comment: Oh, you are right. I totally forgot that Scanner just takes InputStream and works with it. Changing System.in does nothing to it, because that Scanner is already made. Now I'll just make new Scanner in Utility before every test, and that's it. Thanks for help.